# Responsive utilities do Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Olá,

Utilizo o grid do Bootstrap 3 nos meus projetos, e agora estou migrando para a versão 4.

Na versão 3 eu uso além do grid, uma opção de layout chamada responsive utilities que complementa o grid. Consigo baixar esse CSS na opção de Customise download que tem na versão 3.

Porém agora que comecei a usar a versão 4, não consigo encontrar a versão 4 da responsive utilities, e não quero misturar a versão 4 do grid com a versão 3 do responsive utilities.

Eu gosto de baixar os arquivos sem npm, e não utilizo sass. Faço do jeito tradicional mesmo, então se alguém souber alguma resposta que não utilize essas ferramentas vai me ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Opa, beleza?

Vamos lá, se você baixou o bootstrap 4 através [desse link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v4.0.0-beta/bootstrap-4.0.0-beta-dist.zip), você já tem todo os estilos de responsive utilities.

Se você quer migrar do 3 para o 4, algumas classes mudaram de nome, [aqui na documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#common-display-values) tá explicando melhor como fazer a migração.

Comment: Oi, sim no Bootstrap completo tem mesmo, porém não uso nem metade dos estilos que tem nele, uso somente o grid e o responsive utilities (e também o reboot). O problema de eu usar o arquivo completo, é que mesmo minificado, ele tem mais de 120kb, e se eu pegar só grid, reboot e responsive utilities não dá nem 40kb. Na versão 3 eu tinha essa página aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/ que me permitia baixar só o que eu queria, mas não encontro nada para a versão 4.

Comment: Agora entendi seu problema Leandro, não sei se isso ajuda, mas a versão [completa do Bootstrap 4](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css) tem apenas 21kb (via MaxCDN).

Comment: Pois não existe mais (ou ainda) essa customização do pacote na versão 4 do Bootstrap.

Comment: Obrigado Vinicius, quase ctz q eles vão lançar a opção de customizar o Bootstrap 4 assim que sair do beta. Eu encontrei um cara que teve a paciência de separar o grid e o responsive utilities manualmente, ele postou no Github nesse link, pra quem estiver procurando o mesmo que eu https://github.com/m-spyratos/bootstrap-4-grid/tree/master/css